# How to retrieve the position of a node in the existing scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, sketchup

I created a model(for example, building with four walls) and exported it as .dea file using Sketchup. Later i add tap guesture to the scene and find out which wall on the scene have been tapped. I got results -  exact name (id) of the wall but i didn't get the position. The position always - (x:0 , y:0, z:0). I want to add a new SCNNode to each wall i tapped, so i need exact position of the wall in the scene.

Screenshot:

[image]

As in screenshot, i tapped on front side wall of first building, but the result is zero vector.

I tried every solution on stackOverflow and Internet too, but didn't success. Can anybody help me?

dae file:

http://www.filefactory.com/file/40y2ef86hgm3/Sample3d.dae

Code:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class SceneViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    //Data handlers
    var currentSceneView: SCNView? = nil
    var cameraOrbit = SCNNode()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    var sceneText = SCNText()

    //HANDLE PAN CAMERA
    var lastWidthRatio: Float = 0
    var lastHeightRatio: Float = 0.2
    var WidthRatio: Float = 0
    var HeightRatio: Float = 0.2
    var fingersNeededToPan = 1
    var maxWidthRatioRight: Float = 0.2
    var maxWidthRatioLeft: Float = -0.2
    var maxHeightRatioXDown: Float = 0.02
    var maxHeightRatioXUp: Float = 0.4

    //HANDLE PINCH CAMERA
    var pinchAttenuation = 20.0  //1.0: very fast ---- 100.0 very slow
    var lastFingersNumber = 0
    var myScene = SCNScene()


   // MARK: - View Lifecycle methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "Sample3d.dae")!


        myScene = scene

        addCameraNode(scene: scene)
        prepareScene(scene: scene)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    // MARK: - Private APIs


    func addCameraNode(scene : SCNScene){
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = SCNLight.LightType.omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        //  scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        cameraNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        //   scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
        cameraNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        //Create a camera like Rickster said
        camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
        camera.orthographicScale = 1
        //camera.orthographicScale = 100
        camera.zNear = 1
        camera.zFar = 100

        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 20)
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        cameraOrbit = SCNNode()
        cameraOrbit.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraOrbit)
    }

    func prepareScene(scene : SCNScene){
        self.navigationItem.title = "3D Scene"
        //initial camera setup
        self.cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.y = Float(-3 * M_PI) * lastWidthRatio
        self.cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.x = Float(-M_PI) * lastHeightRatio

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

        currentSceneView = scnView

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        //allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = false  //not needed

        // add a tap gesture recognizer
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SceneViewController.handlePan(_:)))
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        // add a pinch gesture recognizer
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SceneViewController.handlePinch(_:)))
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SceneViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    // MARK: - Guesture Recognition methods

    func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let location: CGPoint = gestureRecognize.location(in: currentSceneView)// for example from a tap gesture recognizer
        let hits = self.currentSceneView?.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        if let tappedNode = hits?.first?.node {
addVideoNodeToScene(presentNode: tappedNode)

        }
    }


func addVideoNodeToScene(presentNode: SCNNode){

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sample", ofType: "mp4") {
            let videoUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl as URL)
            let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
            let size = CGSize(width: 1024, height: 512)
            videoNode.size = size
            videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2.0,y :size.height/2.0)
            let spriteScene = SKScene(size: size)
            spriteScene.addChild(videoNode)

            let cubeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            cubeMaterial.diffuse.contents = spriteScene
            cubeMaterial.isDoubleSided = true

            let v1 = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 0,z: 0)
            let v2 = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 0,z: 0)
            let dx:Float = Float(v1.x - v2.x)/2.0
            let dy:Float = Float(v1.y - v2.y)

            var plane = SCNPlane()
            plane = SCNPlane.init(width: 0.35, height: 0.35)
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

            plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
            planeNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: Float(M_PI))
            planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = cubeMaterial
            planeNode.position = presentNode.position
            planeNode.position.z = planeNode5.position.z + 0.15

            myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

            videoNode.play()
        }
    }


    func handlePan(_ gestureRecognize: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let numberOfTouches = gestureRecognize.numberOfTouches
        let translation = gestureRecognize.translation(in: gestureRecognize.view!)

        if (numberOfTouches==fingersNeededToPan) {

            WidthRatio = Float(translation.x) / Float(gestureRecognize.view!.frame.size.width) + lastWidthRatio
            HeightRatio = Float(translation.y) / Float(gestureRecognize.view!.frame.size.height) + lastHeightRatio

            //  HEIGHT constraints
            if (HeightRatio >= maxHeightRatioXUp ) {
                HeightRatio = maxHeightRatioXUp
            }
            if (HeightRatio <= maxHeightRatioXDown ) {
                HeightRatio = maxHeightRatioXDown
            }

            //  WIDTH constraints
            if(WidthRatio >= maxWidthRatioRight) {
                WidthRatio = maxWidthRatioRight
            }
            if(WidthRatio <= maxWidthRatioLeft) {
                WidthRatio = maxWidthRatioLeft
            }

            self.cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.y = Float(-5 * M_PI) * WidthRatio
            self.cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.x = Float(-2 * M_PI) * HeightRatio

            //print("Height: \(round(HeightRatio*100))")
            //print("Width: \(round(WidthRatio*100))")

            //for final check on fingers number
            lastFingersNumber = fingersNeededToPan
        }

        lastFingersNumber = (numberOfTouches>0 ? numberOfTouches : lastFingersNumber)

        if (gestureRecognize.state == .ended && lastFingersNumber==fingersNeededToPan) {
            lastWidthRatio = WidthRatio
            lastHeightRatio = HeightRatio
            //print("Pan with \(lastFingersNumber) finger\(lastFingersNumber>1 ? "s" : "")")
        }

    }

    func handlePinch(_ gestureRecognize: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        let pinchVelocity = Double.init(gestureRecognize.velocity)
        //print("PinchVelocity \(pinchVelocity)")

        camera.orthographicScale -= (pinchVelocity/pinchAttenuation)

        //print("PinchVelocity \(camera.orthographicScale)")

        if camera.orthographicScale <= 0.5 {
            camera.orthographicScale = 0.5
        }

        if camera.orthographicScale >= 5 {
            camera.orthographicScale = 5
        }

    }

    // MARK: - ViewController Orientation methods

    override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Status bar methods

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785453/how-to-get-the-real-position-of-a-sub-node-in-scenekit-after-rotation ?

Comment: @Harvant S. i tried but not working..pls check the code

Comment: Code looks okay to me. Could you please provide me `Scene Graph` of your `dae` file ?

Comment: @Harvant S please check attached dae file

Answer (score 1):

In the file you attached, each node is positioned on `(0, 0, 0)` but have different `euler angle`. As i am checking with other 3d models, your code working absolutely fine. Contact your 3d designer and ask him/her to fix the model.

I will suggest you to open `dae` in editor (Xcode) make every `euler angle` to `(0, 0, 0)` and change position of nodes according to requirements.

Comment: Can you please attach a sample 3D model to your answer. I want to check it.

Comment: Sorry i can't due to NDA. I can suggest you do something. Open dae in editor (Xcode) make every `euler angle` to `(0, 0, 0)` and change position of nodes according to requirements. It may take some time.